# An inequality involving multi-index

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, inequalities

I came across these inequalities while learning about Schwartz functions (Classical Fourier Analysis, Grafakos) and I have no idea how to prove this:

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\alpha = (\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{n}) \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$, we set

$$ x^{\alpha} = x_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots x_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}.$$

Then prove that there exists a constant $c_{n,\alpha}$ such that

> **$$\left| x^{\alpha}\right| \leq c_{n,\alpha}|x|^{|\alpha|}$$**

where $|\alpha| = \alpha_{1} + \cdots + \alpha_{n}$.

Conversely, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $C_{n,k}$ such that

> $$|x|^{k} \leq C_{n,k}\sum\limits_{|\beta| = k}|x^{\beta}|$$

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Please let me know if the question is too elementary for this forum.

Comment: What is $|x|$? The Euclidean or $l_2$ norm?

Comment: $|x| = \sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + \cdots + x_{n}^{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality with constant 1 follows from
$
\vert x^\alpha\vert\le\Vert x\Vert_{\infty}^{\vert \alpha \vert},\quad\text{where $\Vert x\Vert_{\infty}$ is the sup-norm.}
$

The second equality, also with constant 1, is due to  $
\Vert x\Vert_{\infty}^k=\max_{1\le j\le n} \vert x_j\vert^k\le \max_{\vert \alpha\vert=k}
\vert x^\alpha\vert.
$

Comment: Although I meant the Euclidean norm, but this is good enough as I can use the inequalities between these two norms.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the first inequality the constant is $1$ actually. I note $|\boldsymbol\alpha|=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n$ and $\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol\alpha}=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$

The geometric mean inequality states that if $\beta_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i=1$ then for positive numbers $x_i\geq 0$ and $q>0$:
\begin{equation}
x_1^{\beta_1} \cdots x_d^{\beta_n} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i x_i^{q})^{1/q}
\end{equation}
Applying this for $|x_i|$, and $\beta_i=\alpha_i/|\boldsymbol\alpha|$ gives:
\begin{equation}
(|x_1|^{\alpha_1} \cdots |x_n|^{\alpha_n})^{1/|\boldsymbol\alpha|}\leq \frac{1}{|\boldsymbol\alpha|^{1/q}} (\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i |x_i|^{q})^{1/q}
\end{equation}
So:
\begin{equation}
|\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol\alpha}|\leq \frac{1}{|\boldsymbol\alpha|^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q}}(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\alpha_i |x_i|^{q})^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q}
\end{equation}
But $\alpha_i\leq |\boldsymbol\alpha|$ so:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol\alpha|^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i |x_i|^{q})^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q} \leq \frac{|\boldsymbol\alpha|^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q}}{|\boldsymbol\alpha|^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i|^{q})^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q} 
\end{equation}
Hence:
\begin{equation}
|\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol\alpha}|\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^{q})^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|/q}
\end{equation}
Taking $q=2$ gives:
\begin{equation}
|\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol\alpha}|\leq \|\mathbf{x}\|^{|\boldsymbol\alpha|}
\end{equation}